# In plotly, how do I retain the information about both the lasso selection and the clicked point?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, ggplotly

I'm using `plotly::ggplotly()` and I need the user to be able to both select a single point and to select multiple points with brushing. I want both selection options to exist in parallel. The user should be able to click on a point and to lasso select several points, and both of those pieces of information should be recorded.

The problem I'm having is that if I click on a point, then the lasso selection gets reset. But the opposite is not true: if I lasso select and then click on a point, then both are retained.

Here's a GIF of this issue

[image]

Here's my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  verbatimTextOutput("click"),
  verbatimTextOutput("brush")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  nms <- row.names(mtcars)

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, key = nms)) + geom_point()
    ggplotly(p) %>% layout(dragmode = "lasso")
  })

  output$click <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_click")
    if (!is.null(d)) d
  })

  output$brush <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_selected")
    if (!is.null(d)) d
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

To reproduce:

- Click a single point
- Do a lasso selection
- Both are currently visible
- Click a different point
- Now the lasso selection information is gone
- Do a lasso selection again, both are visible again

Comment: I literally tried all my test cases including a html template, nothing leads to anywhere, Did you try installing dev version of ggplot2?

Comment: It works fine for me. Here's my `sessionInfo()`: R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30), Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit), Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200), plotly_4.5.6  ggplot2_2.2.1 shiny_1.0.5

Comment: Would it bother you if the click and brush info were in the same box? You could always add a click/brush column? I achieved this by putting the click and brush event_data in the same renderPrint and passing it out as one frame

Comment: Turns out this is an actual bug with plotly. I was asked to file a bug report https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1121

Answer (score 1):

If you pass the `event_data` to an object outside the `renderPrint()` function this should work. You can also keep previous lasso/click results if you remove the optional lines highlighted below:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    plotlyOutput("plot"),
    verbatimTextOutput("click"),
    verbatimTextOutput("brush")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    frame1 <- data.frame()
    frame2 <- data.frame()
    nms <- row.names(mtcars)

    output$plot <- renderPlotly({
        p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt, key = nms)) + geom_point()
        ggplotly(p) %>% layout(dragmode = "lasso")
    })

    output$click <- renderPrint({
        d <- event_data("plotly_click")
        if (!is.null(d)) {
            frame1 <<- frame1[is.null(frame1$pointNumber), ] # Optional line to remove the previous selections
            frame1 <<- rbind(frame1, d) 
        }
            frame1
        })

    output$brush <- renderPrint({
        d <- event_data("plotly_selected")
        if (!is.null(d)) {
            frame2 <<- frame2[is.null(frame2$pointNumber), ] # Optional line to remove the previous selections 
            frame2 <<- rbind(frame2, d)
        }
            frame2

    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I was hoping to be able to do it natively with plotly, without having to make a custom workaround by keeping track of the state. I wanted to know how to get plotly to not override the selection. Turns out it's a bug with plotly